# switch ios simulator always reports error

Tags: ios

Each time when I switch ios simulator and click 'Run' always reports error

```
 Xcode cannot run using the selected device, 
 choose a destination with a supported architecture.
```

it also change my product name to ${PRODCUT_NAME} on simulator.

If I clean and run again, it will start correctly.

but the name on simulator still display ${PRODCUT_NAME}.

I have to remove the app on simulator, clean and run again, everything is ok.

But if I run again, it will reports

```
ios simulator failed to install the application.
```

I need to clean again to run.

```
building settings

Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

Bace SDK :latest iOS 7.0

Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s

ios deployment target 4.3

Default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.0)
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: Hey have you tried Reset Contents and settings

Comment: how to reset Contents and settings ?

Comment: click iOS Simulator in left corner -> Reset Contents and settings

Comment: which version ios unable to run @arachide

Comment: all version, need to clean

Comment: do you reset the simulator

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Select iOS Simulator from dock and go to menu as per above pic

Answer (score 0):

Change your Architectures setting

[image]